# Determine accuracy of a given date string

Tags: javascript, date

Given a date string, parsed with `new Date`, how can I determine the accuracy?

#### Examples

**Year**

```
let date = new Date('2017')
// Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00
```

**Month**

```
let date = new Date('2017-10')
// Sun Oct 01 2017 00:00:00

let date = new Date('oct 2017')
// Sun Oct 01 2017 00:00:00
```

**Day**

```
let date = new Date('2017.3.15')
// Wed Mar 15 2017 00:00:00


let date = new Date('3 15 17')
// Wed Mar 15 2017 00:00:00
```

---

I can't just check if the month is january to see if the accuracy is `year`, as the month may be january, obviously.

```
new Date('2017').getMonth() // 0
new Date('2017 1').getMonth() // 0
```

Also, using `RegExp` is difficult as there is a great variation of formats supported by the `Date` parser.

Is it possible to determine the accuracy of a date string with the built-in `Date` (or other built-ins), and if so, how?

---

Edit: the end goal is to create an array of date parts (i.e. `[year, month, day]`), and, for example, if the day is omitted in the input, it should be omitted in the output as well.

```
'2017 2 3' -> [2017, 2, 3]
'2017 4' -> [2017, 4]
'2017' -> [2017]
```

If the solution to that problem is different from the solution to the problem mentioned above, that would work too, but I don't think there's any solution that wouldn't solve the problem above as well.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this accuracy? This seems to me you're trying to achieve something the wrong way.

Comment: @Zenoo I have a date string as input, and an array of date parts (i.e. [year, month, day]) as output. If the day is missing in the date string, it shouldn't be present in the array either.

Comment: Imagine the user enters `2017 1 1` and `2017`. What should your final array look like? And why don't you precise the year/month/day every time ? Why do you need the accuracy?

Comment: @Zenoo if possible, `'2017 1 1' -> [2017, 1, 1]` and `'2017' -> [2017]`. I don't control the input. The accuracy is to convert different data schemes as good as possible, without information loss.

Comment: You won't be able to control that using a `Date` object, you'll have to use the base String. What are the possible date formats you're receiving ?

Comment: It's already virtually impossible to work with arbitrary unknown date formats, adding unknown accuracy to that mix makes it even less possible. You need to take more control over your date formats, there's no automagic solution `Date` can offer.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I thought perhaps there would be a solution I missed, since `Date` does 'know' more or less (it fills in the missing parts). I'll see if I can limit the input in some way. Should I close the question @deceze?

Comment: You should consider that `Date` is not guarantee to give you the values you wrote in your question. Date must support just few representation.

Comment: Other than the limited subset of ISO 8601 noted in ECMA-262, the behaviour of the built-in parser is entirely implementation dependent. To expect all implementations to consistently parse random date–like strings is unreasonable and certainly inconsistent across browsers. To accurately parse anything you must know the format, valid ranges and meaning of the tokenised parts.